# Override justify-content-between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

here i am again, i recently solved a problem where I could not get the navbar brand to go into the middle of my nav bar, however, that was fixed, but now I want to add a button right before the right navigation toggle. I have tried multiple ways, like text-align, and a few other methods that bootstrap has like `d-flex`. however I cannot seem to override the `justify-content-between` so i can get my sign up button to appear right before the right navigation toggle. I have left a photo below for better reference. I have also included the code for my navigation bar below the photo link. thanks in advance!
[image: picture of what I am trying to accomplish]

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Dark offcanvas navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftMainNav" aria-controls="leftMainNav" aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img src="assets/images/logo-l.png" class="img-fluid" alt="CBS Logo">
                CherryBerry <span class="text-red"> Studios </span>
              </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start text-bg-dark" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: did you try to simply wrap your `button.navbar-toggler` inside a parent div (that will become your flex item) containing also the element you are going to add before?

Comment: @DiegoD Could you please clarify? I dont quite understand what you are getting at here. I should also mention that all of the navbar elements have to be inside the `container-fluid` div element in order for the navbar button togglers and brand name to be positioned the way they are now.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't really know what other code there is to show. Currently, i have all the code used for my navbar to show how it is built, showing how it is formatted using bootstrap. My main issue is I need to place the sign-up button right before the right nav toggle button, however when I try using `justify-content-between`, it just evenly spaces all of the buttons out, however I just want the sign-up button to be right in front of the right navbar toggle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace some code...

```
<!-- replace this lines (right toggler) -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- with the below code -->
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" aria-label="sign up">
    <span>Sign up</span>
  </button>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to say in comments, was that since you already have a flex container and your toggler button as a flex item, instead of messing up the justify-content, you may just wrap that element inside a new div container and include inside it the element that should be next to the already existing one.

This is in detail the modification:

```
  <div class="toggler-container">
    <div class="signup">sign up</div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

And this is the whole demo:

```css
.signup{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: .2em;
  color: red;
  
  /* same sizing as the sibling */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;  
  border-radius: 0.25rem;  
  
  /* will stretch the height of signup to be as much as the container */  
  align-self: stretch;  
}

/*this is just to style the container of signup and hamburger toggler*/
.toggler-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Dark offcanvas navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftMainNav" aria-controls="leftMainNav" aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img src="assets/images/logo-l.png" class="img-fluid" alt="CBS Logo"> CherryBerry <span class="text-red"> Studios </span>
      </a>
      <div class="toggler-container">
        <div class="signup">sign up</div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start text-bg-dark" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```